# Getting invalid json in RoR

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, json

I have an array sku = `["MAPNQ20673"]`. On converting this to json using sku.to_json I'm getting `"[\"MAPNQ20673\"]"`. This is an invalid json. I need to pass this array to a python script.

```
system "python2 /home/nish/stuff/repos/Untitled/voylla_staging_changes/app/models/ReviseItem.py #{sku.to_json} #{qtys.to_json}"
```

Then, I am using `json.loads(sys.argv[1])` to decode. But since the json is invalid, I am getting the following error on decoding the json in python script:

```
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

How can i convert the array to a valid json?

**EDIT:** It works fine for me when I call the python script from a standalone ruby program. But when I rty to do the same from controller of an RoR app, it fails

Comment: How are you converting it to json? where is your actual code?

Comment: You should probably read a little about python and json objects. That code makes no sense (or, alternatively look at James Mills's answer on how to do it)

Comment: How are you calling the Python script from Ruby?

Comment: @yuvi : I have posted an edit, it works fine when used in standalone mode but does not in RoR app. Am scratching my head as to why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

This works prefectly for me with **Python 2.7**:

```
>>> from json import dumps, loads
>>> sku = ["MAPNQ20673"]
>>> s = dumps(sku)
>>> x = loads(s)
>>> x == sku
True
>>> x
[u'MAPNQ20673']
```

Comment: Yeah, It works fine for me when I call it from a standalone ruby program. But when I rty to do the same from RoR app I get an invalid json.

Comment: Then I suggest you find out where your encoding/decoding is going wrong. You are going from Python <-> Ruby on Rails?